# cloning and appending row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I perform the following action using jquery?

I have a table with three rows and a header row. something like this:
When a user enters Data in "StudentId" field, "StudentFirstName" and "StudentLastName" are populated from database using jquery-Ajax. What I want to achieve is, Once a studentId is entered in first row textbox, I want to clone the first row and append it as second row and then clear the data from first row.

Hers is my Table structure:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyModel.Model" %>
<div>
<table id="MyTableHeaders">
        <tr>
            <th>
                StudentId
            </th>
            <th>
                StudentFirstName
            </th>
            <th>
                StudentLastName
            </th>            
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div>
<table id="MyTableData">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="StudentId"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="StudentFirstName"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="StudentLastName"/>
            </td>            
        </tr>    
</table>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$('input[name="StudentId"]').focusout(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = '/Student/DisplayStudentDetails';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        data: { id: $('input[name="StudentId"]').val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $('input[name="StudentFirstName"]').val(result.FirstName);
            $('input[name="StudentLastName"]').val(result.LastName);
            $("#MyTableData tr:first").clone().appendTo("#MyTableData");
            $("#MyTableData tr:first").find("input").attr("value", "").blur();
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Failed")
        }
    });
});
```

I am struggling with clearing data from first row and keeping data in the cloned row. With my code it clears all the rows.

Also, I noticed that cloned rows have the same field names, hence it will update all cloned "StudentFirstName" and "StudentLastName" fields with the studentId entered in first row. How should I approach this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cant append a row to a row, append the row to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    success: function (result) {
        var clone = $("#MyTableData tr:first").clone();
        clone.find('input[name="StudentId"]').val(result.FirstName);
        clone.find('input[name="StudentFirstName"]').val(result.FirstName);
        clone.find('input[name="StudentLastName"]').val(result.LastName);
        $("#MyTableData ").append(clone);
    },
```

-edit-

although, when i've attempted tasks such as this in the past, i've created template rows.
a row that already exists but has display:none.  that way if your table has no values you can always know the template row exists.

-edit-
if you want to add the new row at the begining, you can just use prepend instead of append.
or the second row would be $("#MyTableData tr").first().after(clone)

Comment: The solution works, but it appends current row(first row) at the end(last row), anyway we can append the current row as second row instead of last?